Sequelize Many-to-Many on same table
I have a user:
@Table({
    underscored: true,
})
export default class User extends Model {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    id: string;

    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column
    name: string;

    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column
    username: string;

    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column
    password: string;

    @BelongsToMany(() => User, () => Follow, 'followeeId')
    followers: Follow[]

    @BelongsToMany(() => User, () => Follow, 'followerId')
    following: Follow[]
}

and a follows table:
@Table({
    underscored: true,
})
export default class Follow extends Model {
    @ForeignKey(() => User)
    @Column
    followerId: string;

    @ForeignKey(() => User)
    @Column
    followeeId: string;
}

Now I try to load a user record with all of its followers and following:
const follows = await User.findByPk(req.userId, {
    include: [Follow, Follow]
})

But getting this from sequelize: EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Follow is not associated to User!
What am I doing wrong?

The right way:
@BelongsToMany(() => User, () => Follow, 'followerId')
followers: User[]

@BelongsToMany(() => User, () => Follow, 'followeeId')
following: User[]

and then
const user = await User.findByPk(req.userId, {
    include: [{
        model: User,
        as: 'followers'
    },{
        model: User,
        as: 'following'
    }]
})

